# calling php contents from two different buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php file and I have created 2 buttons get and set in the file.

I want to access Get.php file when I click get

```
<?php
 $file = "xxx.json";
 include 'Get.php';
 ob_start();
 formatPara("0");
 $output = ob_get_clean();
 file_put_contents($file,$output);
 ?>
```

and Set.php file when I select set button.

```
 <?php
 $file = "xxx.json";
 include 'Set.php';
 ob_start();
 formatPara("0");
 $output = ob_get_clean();
 file_put_contents($file,$output);
 ?>
```

My file visual.php file contents are:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <meta charset="utf-8">

 <?php
 $file = "xxx.json";
 include 'Get.php';
 ob_start();
 formatPara("0");
 $output = ob_get_clean();
 file_put_contents($file,$output);
 ?>

 <style>
right { 
display:table-cell; 
vertical-align:top; 
width:300px; 
padding:0 5px;
 }

<?php 
$color=include('Color.php');
echo $color;
?>   
</style>

    <body>
<div id=tt>
     <button type="submit" onclick="get()"> <b>get</b></button>
     <button type="submit" onclick="set()"> <b>set</b></button>
</div>
     <div id=graph>
<script src="ll.js"></script>
<script src="visual.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


window.onload = function(){
}
<?php
$link=include('Link.php');
echo $link;
?>
</script>
</div>
    <body>
```

I am not sure how can I get the contents for Get.php file and Set.php file. I know that I can call ajax calls. But in that case only I can get the contents of the Get.php or Set.php files.
But how can I also make other data shown below execute in sequential order.

```
<?php
 $file = "xxx.json";
 include 'Get.php';
 ob_start();
 formatPara("0");
 $output = ob_get_clean();
 file_put_contents($file,$output);
 ?>
```

I am new to php. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Have you ever heard about `if` and `switch...case` statements?

Comment: Where are your `get()` and `set()` functions defined?

Answer (score 0):

Bes way, is using standard html methods: name-value for form elements

```
<body>
<form method="GET">
  <button type="submit" name="event" value="get"> <b>get</b></button>
  <button type="submit" name="event" value="set"> <b>set</b></button>
</form>
<body>
```

And the php code:

```
$file = "xxx.json";

switch ($_GET['event'])
{
    case 'get': include 'Get.php'; break;
    case 'set': include 'Set.php'; break;
}

ob_start();
formatPara("0");
$output = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents($file,$output);
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy. I tried the code but its not working. May be I have missed some of the code in file thats why. Below the buttons I am also displaying a graph. I have edited the code and can you see whats going wrong? I am getting Internal 500 error.

Comment: 500 error, it is your script contains mistake. Try debug your script to find which line will broken the script

Answer (score 0):

Dmitriy's answer is pretty easy, and clean looking. I like.
Ive made a little longer example, utilizing a class aswell, and commented it throughoutly for you to perhaps learn a little or two. Hope it helps!

```
<?php
    class HandleFile {

        protected $file;

        //The construct is called, when the object is created. We request the file here.
        public function __construct($file = null) {
            //Lets check if the file variable is set or not.
            if( !is_null($file) ) {
                //Lets check if the file actually exists
                if( file_exists($file) ) {
                    //If the file exists, set the class variable.
                    $this->file = $file;
                } else {
                    //If the file does not exist. Throw an exception
                    throw new Exception("Construct:: The file " . $file . ", does not exist.");
                }
            } else {
                    //If the file variable is not set, throw an exception.
                    throw new Exception("Construct:: No file specified.");
            }
        }

        //This function will do our actual logic.
        public function doAction($fileToInclude) {
            //First, check if the file to include exists.
            if( file_exists($fileToInclude) ) {
                //Include it
                include($fileToInclude);
                ob_start();
                formatPara("0");
                $output = ob_get_clean();
                file_put_contents($this->file,$output);
            } else {
                //If it does not exist. Throw exception.
                throw new Exception("doAction:: File " . $fileToInclude . ", does not exist.");
            }
        }
    }

    //Try/catch. Tries the action and if an error is trown, catch it and output the message.
    try {
        $Handler = new HandleFile("xxx.json");
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        print $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
    }
    //Define a helper variable
    $action = null;

    //If the GET parameter "get" is set, do a get action
    if( isset( $_GET['get'] ) ) {
        $action = "Get.php";

    //If the GET parameter "post" is set, do a post action.
    } elseif( isset( $_GET['post'] ) ) {
        $action = "Post.php";
    }

    //If our helper variable has changed, there must be an action to do.
    if( !is_null($action) ) {
         //Try/catch. Tries the action and if an error is trown, catch it and output the message.
        try {
            $Handler->doAction($action);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            print $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
        }
    }
?>

<body>
 <form action="" method="GET">
     <button type="submit" name="get" value="yes"> <b>get</b></button>
     <button type="submit" name="post" value="yes"> <b>set</b></button>
 </form>
<body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're calling a function which isn't set...

why don't you use $_POST
to with 2 different forms

1 hidden input contains the id type

if the type is get then include the get

if the type is set then include the set

this is just an example tho'

Comment: You should consider taking yourself a little more time to write your answers. For a "just starting in php" person, this is like quantum physics for a 3 year old. Not very community helping! Cheer Cheer. Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I sent it from an iphone so don't expect codes into it when I am on the iphone I just answer with the logics people can add and not codes. if'd have to send codes with it from an iphone screen it would be a pain in my ass ;)

Comment: i Agree. Perhaps, next time, consider if a post is worth answering without codes. You might just, without knowing so, add more confusion than help. Though, your logic with the post is good :)